How select query from record count more than 2 in MS Access
I'm trying to select query from row count more than 2 based on ID and DATE in MS Access.
Please Guide me
I want to keep it as a single query.
Thanks
Table Absen



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5008
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5008
28-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5009
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5010
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
POSITIONID




5008
A
STAFF


5009
B
STAFF


5010
C
STAFF


5011
D
STAFF



I used this SQL code result like this:
select a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
from ABSEN a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
where exists(select 1 from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID)
order by a.ID, a.DATE

Result From code



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5008
A
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5008
A
28-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5009
B
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5009
B
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5009
B
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5010
C
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



Desired output



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5009
B
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5009
B
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5009
B
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT




User D has both IN and OUT time in the same date. What is business logic to add three records of User D in the desired output?

Try a GROUP BY subquery in the WHERE clause to get the ID's having at least one count per day > 2.
select a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
from ABSEN a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
where a.id IN (select ID
               from ABSEN
               group by ID, date
               having count(*) > 2)
order by a.ID, a.DATE

